# Finite solvable group with cyclic Fitting subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group such that $F(G)$( i.e. Fitting subgroup of $G$) is cyclic. I want to prove that $G$ is supersolvable.

I know since $G$ is solvable, $C_G(F(G)) \leq F(G)$, and so $C_G(F(G)) = F(G)$.
Thus $G/F(G) \hookrightarrow Aut(F(G))$. It follows that $G^{\prime} \leq F(G)$ and $G"=1$. Now why $G$ is supersolvable?

Comment: That seems clear from  $F(G)$ cyclic and $G' \le F(G)$. Take any polycyclic series whose first term is $F(G)$, and all subgroups in that series are normal, so $G$ is supersolvble.

Comment: @ derek Holt. $1 \trianglelefteq G' \trianglelefteq F(G) \trianglelefteq G$, why $G/ F(G)$ is cyclic?

Comment: I didn't say $G/F(G)$ is cyclic. It's abelian and hence supersovable

Comment: $G$ is supersolvable if it has a normal series all of whose factor are cyclic.

Comment: Thus $G/F(G)$ must be cyclic. I dont understand this point!

Comment: And I don't understand your comments, It is not necessarily true that $G/F(G)$ is cyclic (it's not true in the direct product of dihedral groups of orders $6$ and $10$ for example), and I never said that it was. So why do you keep saying that it is?

Comment: We need a normal series with cyclic factors ok? what is it?

Comment: $G/F(G)$ is abelian, so it has a normal series with cyclic factors. Also $F(G)$ is cyclic. So we get a normal series for $G$ with cyclic factors.

Comment: Thats right, thank you very much